# Can an active iOS app know when a push notification is being displayed for a different app?

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm working on an iOS game that has a score counter and some buttons at the top of the screen. When I receive any push notifications for a different app (e.g. a new email), the push notification covers the top of the screen for a few seconds, which is annoying when you're in the middle of a game. I would like to know whenever a third-party notification is being displayed, so that I can move the score counter and buttons below the push notification while it is being shown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now (and probably forever) there is no API or way to interact with Apple's Notification Center, and thus it's impossible to know when a third-party notification is displaying. This is primarily because they strive to keep a consistent user experience across their entire platform at the developer's expense. The closest you can get is knowing when an application has left and entered the foreground (which will happen when they tap that notification) to properly pause the game

Thankfully, users can dismiss the alerts really quickly with a swipe of a thumb, but regardless, it's still annoying. Maybe make some small adjustments to your UI with this knowledge and have less user taps necessary at the top of the screen?

Good luck!

Comment: Ah that's a shame, thanks though!